# Is $f$ uniformly continuous

Tags: continuity

Prove/Disprove : Let $f:(0,1)→\mathbb{R}$ be Continuous. The condition $f(1/n)$$\rightarrow$$1/2$ and $f(1/n^2)$$\rightarrow$$1/4$  imply that $f $ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: In fact, the condition implies $f$ is *not* uniformly continuous.

Comment: any counterexample? @ David Mitra

Comment: Actually, the two conditions can't hold simultaneously.

Comment: If $f$ were uniformly continuous, there would be a uniformly continuous extension $F\colon [0,1] \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Why not? $f$ is only defined on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Neal $(1/n^2)$ is a subsequence of $(1/m)$.

Comment: Oh ho ho ho, joke's on me.

Comment: Disregarding this, just argue directly: any nhood $(0,\delta)$ contains points $x$, $y$ with $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge 1/8$.

Comment: I guess it would be more precise to say $\geq 1/8$. Regardless of the fact that this condition is absurd :p

Comment: @user48805 Of course, thanks. Corrected ...

Comment: @drhab Of course. I'm just imagining the question was well-posed...

Answer (score 1):

The condition implies everything! This because it is not true.

($f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\rightarrow2$ implies: $f\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)\rightarrow2$
wich contradicts $f\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)\rightarrow4$)

$p\rightarrow q$ is true if $p$ is not true.

So indeed the condition implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous. There is no function that satisfies this condition and is not uniformly continuous. You cannot even find a function that satisfies this condition.

Answer (score 0):

there is no function that satisfy this condition. let $k \in (1,\infty)$ then $ f(\frac{1}{k}) \to \frac{1}{2}$  and  $f(\frac{1}{k^2}) \to\frac{1}{4}$ .

now introduce some $m=\sqrt{k}$ what do you observe.

you get a $f(\frac{1}{k}) \to \frac{1}{4}$
this means that a value of $x$ has $2$ different values of function.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out in other answers, the conditions are self-contradictory; the sequence $f(1/n^2)$ is a subsequence of $f(1/n)$. If they have limits at all, they cannot have different ones.

It seems to me that the spirit of the question is to ask,

> if $a_n,\ b_n\to 0$ but $\lim f(a_n)\neq \lim f(b_n)$, then can $f$ be uniformly continuous?

Now my hint is: $f$ cannot extend to a continuous function $\hat{f}:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$. (Can you see why?) Why does this imply $f$ must not be uniformly continuous?

Comment: no. I cann't see @ Neal

Comment: @Mathematics  Hint: the value of $f$ at $0$ must not depend on the sequence used to approach $0$.

Comment: give a counterexample!

Comment: The conditions taken together also imply that $f$ *can* extend to a continuous function $\hat{f}:\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. In fact they imply any statement.